# FindFirst cannot access direct network shares?

Tags: c++, borland-c++

I have following network shares:

```
\\server\main
\\server\workDir
```

workDir is subdirectory of main, so

```
\\server\main\workDir
```

also works fine.

When I am executing following code sample, first function call returns 0 as expected, but second and third calls returns code 67 (The network name cannot be found). I checked permission for these directories and shares and they are OK. I can also connect to them via Windows Explorer without a problem.

```
int iError
TSearchRec srFindData;

iError = FindFirst("\\\\server\\main\\workDir", faDirectory, srFindData);
if (iError == 0)
    FindClose(srFindData);
iError = FindFirst("\\\\server\\workDir", faDirectory, srFindData);
if (iError == 0)
    FindClose(srFindData);
iError = FindFirst("\\\\server\\main", faDirectory, srFindData);
if (iError == 0)
    FindClose(srFindData);
```

Do you know why that is happening and how to fix it? I am using Borland Developer Studio 2006.

Comment: Have you tried the Windows API directly?  `FindFirstFile`, `FindNextFile`?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Not yet. I guess it will be my next try.

Comment: try to use IP instead of Host name because windows sharing is a mess and the Host is not working always as it should (especially on networks with more then 20 nodes) also is the sharing computer compatible ? (different windows versions make a lot of trouble) ... btw nice to see that I am not the only one still using BDS2006 Turbo C++

Comment: Using WinAPI calls and IP instead of server name didn't helped. For now I am using indirect names ("\\\\server\\main\\workDir"), as I don't need to do anything in main share (at least for now).